# how to extract text from docx files contaning in different folders

Tags: python, list, loops, python-docx, data-extraction

I am writing a code to extract text from word document with extension of docx. I have a big folder named "EXTRACTION" and this folder contain differents sub-folders (for example : folder 1 , 2 , 3 ect..) and each sub-folder contain from 2 to 10 docx document. I want to extract text from each of those files and put it in a new txt file.

I started writing this code but it is not working  (second version of the code):

```
import os
import glob
import docx



print(os.getcwd())

dirs = dirs = glob.glob('fi*')
path = os.getcwd()

for directory in dirs:
    for filename in directory:
        if filename.endswith(".docx") or filename.endswith(".doc"):
            document = docx.Document(filename)
            #docText = []
            with open('your_file.txt', 'w') as f:
                for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
                    if paragraph.text:
                        #docText.append(paragraph.text)
                        f.write("%s\n" % paragraph.text)
```

This code seems to not work , Could you help me improve

[image]

[image]

Comment: describe your problem in question and when you are open file in `w` mode it Opens a file for writing. Creates a new file if it does not exist or truncates the file if it exists. you should open a file in `a` mode so it can Open for appending at the end of the file without truncating it. Creates a new file if it does not exist.

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can use glob.glob to get a list of all files from subdirectories

```
files = [file for file_list in [glob.glob('/path/to/mainfolder/**/{}'.format(x),recursive=True) for x in ('*.doc','*.docx')] for file in file_list]

with open('your_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for file in files:
        document = docx.Document(filename)    
            for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
                if paragraph.text:
                    f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `directory` is just a string; so `for filename in directory` simply loops over `f`, `i`, `c`, `h`, `i`, `e`, `r` etc.

Also, you were overwriting `your_file.txt` on each iteration. You want to open it once, then loop over the documents you extract from.

```py
import glob
import os

import docx

with open('your_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for directory in glob.glob('fi*'):
        for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, "*")):
            if filename.endswith((".docx", ".doc")):
                document = docx.Document(filename)    
                for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
                    if paragraph.text:
                        #docText.append(paragraph.text)
                        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

You are using `item` without declaring it so there is still a bug here; I can't guess what you hoped for this variable to contain, so I just left it the way it was in your original code.

Comment: thank you , in fact item equal to paragrah.text , I would like to know if writing f.append instead of f.write is also correct , the file i obtain as the exit is quite low comparing to the volume of folder and files so I was wondering if f.write is not overwriting ?

Comment: There is no `append` method but if you `open` with `'a'` instead of `'w'` you append to the end of an existing file. Repeatedly opening and closing the same file is inefficient and silly, though.

Comment: thank you, I have another question some of my data are in table in the doc file how can I proceed to extract from it . I post an image.

Comment: Don't do that. Ask a new question.